# Highchart draw line if there is one point

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have the following chart with 1 point:

[image]

Is there a way to draw a line from this point or convert the point to a line like the following screenshots?

[image]

or

[image]

A fiddle to test: https://jsfiddle.net/ak8xcd7s/

Code:

```js
const chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    max: 100
  },
  xAxis: {
    categories: ['02-2024']
  },
  series: [{
    data: [20],
    pointPlacement: 'on'
  }],
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some possibilites of achieving this. For example you can:

- add path using Highcharts.SVGRenderer

  ```
     chart: {
       events: {
         load() {
           let pointX = this.xAxis[0].toPixels(0),
             pointY = this.yAxis[0].toPixels(0) - this.plotTop - 7;
           this.renderer.path(['M', pointX, pointY, 'L', pointX + 40, pointY, 'z'])
             .attr({
               stroke: this.series[0].points[0].color
             })
             .add();
         }
       }
     },
  ```

  Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xupkzo69/
- add custom symbol as a path or image.
  Examples: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w1879jz3/4/